# A mathematical function to find the median of a sequence

Tags: statistics, functions, median

I want to construct a function

$$f(\{ x_n\}) = x_k $$

where $x_k$ is the median.

The function must be of the form

$$f(\{ x_n\}) = \sum_{k=1}^na_k x_k$$

**Example**

Suppose we want to find the median of $\{x_n\} = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ then since it is ordered we have $\{a_n\} = \{0,0,1,0,0 \}$.

**Question**

What functions do we create to model this mathematically ?

**Attempt**

Let $\{ y_n\}$ be the sorted sequence of $\{x_n\}$.

$$y_1 = \mathrm{min}(\{ x_n\})$$
$$y_k = \mathrm{min}(\{x_{n} \}-\{y_{k-1}\})$$

Then the coefficients are given as

$$a_k= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x_k=y_{n/2} \, \, $} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Comment: You may hide the comparisons but of course the median does "depend on comparisons", so hiding them is at best an aesthetic choice.

Comment: Doesn't the median depend strictly on ordering, and therefore on comparisons? You could try a probabilistic approach, but I'm not sure if you could use that.

Comment: @hardmath By the way, why Prolog?

Comment: @OFRBG:  I like being able to make up the "vocabulary" of a program as it can (done skillfully) make the code somewhat intelligible, and the style of declarative programming goes hand in hand with that.

Comment: Wouldn't the impulse vectors cause trouble when $n$ is even? Because then the median is an average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You desire to express (originally, without "depending on comparisons") the median of $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ in the form of a summation:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n a_k x_k $$

(Note the mistake in using index $n$ rather than $k$ in your Question.)

We must necessarily express each $a_k$ in terms of the $x_j$'s, since no choice of *constant* $a_k$ will work (the median is *not* a linear function of the $x_j$'s, unlike the *mean*, which is a linear function).

Where $n$ is a fixed number, we outline one way to express the $a_k$.  One idea is that when $n$ is odd and all entries are distinct, we want a coefficient $a_k$ that is $1$ when there are both at least $n/2$ entries $x_j$ that are greater than or equal to $x_k$ as well as at least $n/2$ entries that are less than or equal to $x_k$, and otherwise $a_k=0$.  The cases where $n$ is even or some entries can be equal can be handled through modifying this idea to count how many entries are candidates for the median and thereby take an average of them.

One way to disguise such comparisons as arithmetic computations is by using the $\operatorname{sign}(x)$ function, which in turn can be defined in terms of the absolute value function, given some assumption about the arguments $x_j$.